# How to write reduced density matrix of a single site

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

To clear my concepts about density matrices, I am trying to solve the following system as an example.

The density matrix is defined as
$$\rho=|\psi\rangle \langle \psi |$$
where $|\psi\rangle$ is ground state of the system. Let we have a chain of fermions with hopping strength between two nearest neighbor sites $t$ i.e.
$$--\bullet--\bullet--\bullet--\bullet--\bullet--$$
The Hamiltonian can be written as
$$H=t\sum_n c_n^\dagger c_{n+1} + h.c.$$

I want to write reduce density matrix for **single site ($\rho_1$)** and **two sites ($\rho_2$)**.

I do not understand how can I write reduced matrices for both cases.

Comment: This isn’t a general solution. However in this case the Hamiltonian can be diagonalized. Perhaps do it and use the equilibrium expression $\rho=e^{-\beta H}$?

Comment: Note that it's 'reduced' density matrix.